# Add a html attribute to asp.net control (asp:HyperlinkField)

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to know if it's possible to add attribute to asp control like .
I'm using bootstrap and I need to add this attributes (data-toogle, data-remote, data-target).

I need to add them here:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="USER_ID" HeaderText="" datanavigateurlfields="USER_ID"
                datanavigateurlformatstring="~\Delete.aspx?user_id={0}" ControlStyle-CssClass="aDelete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalDialog" data-remote="false"/>
```

Obviously this doesn't work. Wonder if someone could help me with this.

Comment: You can use `Attributes.Add()`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/7a9d6h4f(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Attributes method isn't defined for System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperlinkField

Comment: Looking at the control documentation on MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkfield(v=vs.110).aspx), I found out that it can be done, but it involves a bit more work. Look this article: http://www.dotnetperls.com/htmltextwriter

Comment: Interesting... I will look at that, Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the control, you can add the attribute directly to it e.g.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="foo" runat="server" Text="foo" data-foobar="hello" />
```

Renders as

```
<a id="ctl00_ctl00_plcMain_plcMain_foo" data-foobar="hello">foo</a>
```

Failing that you can access the controls `AttributeCollection` and add it there in the code behind:

```
foo.Attributes.Add("data-foobar", "hello");
```

Comment: Attributes method isn't defined for System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperlinkField

Comment: Did you try adding it straight onto the control as in the first example?

Comment: yes it was the first thing I did, and the asp.net validation message said that the "data-foobar" attribute isn't valid for HyperLinkField. It wasn't an error so I execute it and then it showed me an error "HyperLinkField doesn't have any public property with name 'data-foobar'". So I solved with JQuery and now it works fine like I said in my answer.

Comment: Ah, well glad you got it sorted! :)

Comment: This was very helpful to me as I was needing this on a HyperLink  using code behind. foo.Attributes.Add() worked great!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with JQuery, it seems that "Attributes" class isnt't defined for HyperLinkField so it is impossible to add attributes from CodeBehind or even JavaScript, I think.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.aDelete').click(function () {
            $('#ModalDialog').modal();
        });
    });
```